# Getting value from database and add it's Value?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I call the values from phpmyadmin and I try to add it's value row but when I edit the cell[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSCDW.jpg) it gets the same value

```
       MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port = 3306;username = root;password = ");
        MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("select Fee,Amount from system.other_school_fees ;", conn);

            MySqlDataAdapter ssda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            ssda.SelectCommand = comm;
            DataTable ddbdataset = new DataTable();
            ssda.Fill(ddbdataset);
            BindingSource bbsource = new BindingSource();

            bbsource.DataSource = ddbdataset;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bbsource;
            ssda.Update(ddbdataset);
            dataGridView2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

            int d = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; b++)
            {
                d += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[b].Cells[1].Value);
            }

            lblOSF.Text = d.ToString();
```

[image]

Comment: w8 it should be

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port = 3306;username = root;password = ");


            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("select Miscellaneous_Fee,Amount from system.miscellaneoues;", conn);

Comment: Do you have any code that runs after you edit a cell? Unfortunately it won't recompute itself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
    private int CellSum()
    {
               string a = string.Empty;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++b)
            {
                try
                {
                    int d = 0;
                    d += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[b].Cells[1].Value);
                    sum += d;
                }
                catch 
                {
                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port = 3306;username = root;password = ");
                    MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("select Miscellaneous_Fee,Amount from system.miscellaneoues;", conn);

                    MySqlDataAdapter ssda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    ssda.SelectCommand = comm;
                    DataTable ddbdataset = new DataTable();
                    ssda.Fill(ddbdataset);
                    BindingSource bbsource = new BindingSource();

                    bbsource.DataSource = ddbdataset;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bbsource;
                    ssda.Update(ddbdataset);
                    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Input");
                }

            }
            return sum;     

    }

 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            lblMiscellaneous.Text = CellSum().ToString();
    }
```